# How should I listen to in webRTC?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, webrtc

When I used PC and mobile phone to make a video call through webrtc, the phone suddenly disconnected. At this time, the screen received by the PC suddenly stopped. How should I listen to this situation? Why does Chrome have no RTCPeerConnection.connectionState api?

Comment: [`RTCPeerConnection.onconnectionstatechange`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/RTCPeerConnection/onconnectionstatechange)…?!

Comment: but i can't find this api in the Chrome or FireFox when i create a new RTCPeerConnction Object.

Comment: Have you tried using it as documented? It's an event handler and it's supported in all browsers.

Comment: yes, i run this code in console to check the onconnectionstatechange api,it show undefinded.
code:
 var pc = new RTCPeerConnction();
pc.onconnectionstatechange

Comment: Again, have you tried using it *as documented* and assigned an event listener to it?

Answer (score 0):

try iceconnectionstatechange instead, this is widely implemented unlike connectionstatechange which is not implemented by any browser.